# xslt 1.0: check if any of source nodes contains the text of any of target nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Using xslt 1.0 without extensions only.

Given the examples:

```
<forest>
<hunter>fast antelope</hunter>
<hunter>jumping deer</hunter>
<hunter>large elk</hunter>
<hunter> </hunter>
<prey>rabbit</prey>
<prey>eagle</prey>
<prey>deer</prey>
<prey>elk</prey>
<prey></prey>
</forest>
```

and

```
<forest>
<hunter>fast antelope</hunter>
<hunter>jumping deer</hunter>
<hunter>large elk</hunter>
<hunter> </hunter>
<prey>rabbit</prey>
<prey>eagle</prey>
<prey>fox</prey>
<prey>goose</prey>
<prey></prey>
</forest>
```

how can I write an `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>` test to check that there is at least one `<hunter>` that contains the text of at least one `<prey>`, without matches on empty or whitespace-only text nodes in either `<hunter>` or `<prey>`?

There may be many more nodes, so this must be a text only pattern, no position tricks etc.

My expected result would be a match in example one (based on deer, elk in `<prey>`) and a failure in example two (whitespace-only and empty `text()` nodes).

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't your processor support a `node-set()` extension function?

Comment: on android, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/forest">
    <xsl:variable name="marker">
        <xsl:for-each select="hunter">
            <xsl:if test="../prey[normalize-space()][contains(current(), .)]">1</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <result>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string($marker)">
                <xsl:text>Match</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>No Match</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have not tested this but marking as correct because 1) that is what I was thinking I had to do while mulling after posting, 2) it makes perfect sense to me, and 3) you are who you are ;).

Comment: I suggest you do test this, because I haven't (not thoroughly, anyway). And your 3rd point does not hold water. No one here is infallible.

Comment: It does work, although I added something like `<xsl:for-each select="hunter[normalize-space()]">` to filter out the irrelevant `<hunter>` nodes. As to three, it all depends upon your `scope`. If it gave you a warm and fuzzy feeling knowing that we are grateful for your time and expertise, then `method returns true`.

Comment: LOL, I have no objection to compliments. Still, it's answers that build a reputation, not the other way round.